# How to view the valid period of McAfee antivirus software?

Tags: anti-virus

For those that are using McAfee antivirus software; On my computer, there should be a place to view the validity of my user period, is there a way to see it?

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest thing I could find.  I believe you can use this information to determine when your subscription needs to be renewed.

> How can I renew my subscription?
>
> 1. On your Subscription Information page, click Renew my
>      subscription. You can also renew your subscription from the Home
>      Page by clicking Renew.
> 2. Log in to your McAfee account.
> 3. Find the subscription you want renew on your My Account page, and then click Renew.  If you purchased your McAfee software through an
>      Internet Service Provider (ISP), contact your ISP to renew your
>      subscription.

[Source](http://download.mcafee.com/products/webhelp/4/1033/GUID-BF13A566-685F-4E2A-82D3-6F2BBF92E472.html)

Comment: how do i know what's my Mcafee account, my computer was installed with the software and everytime it runs up automatically?

Comment: @frog - If it came with it installed then you a trial subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your McAfee subscription information from the Home Page.

1   Open the Home Page (Double-click the McAfee icon in your taskbar.)

2   In the protection status area on the Home Page, click Subscription, then click View Settings to open the Subscription Information page.